# Is it possible to use GridFS with Ruby Volt?

Tags: ruby, gridfs, voltrb

I want to store some pictures in the database and was thinking about using GridFS to do it efficiently. Is it possible to use GridFS in the Ruby Volt framework? If so, how does one go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, we don't have a way to use gridfs at the moment.  You can get access to the raw mongo adaptor with:

```
Volt::DataStore.fetch.db
```

You probably don't want the gridfs entry in the same mongo collection as your using as a volt model.